# i have two water tank with same dimension and height therefore have the same water pressure, if I combine the two tank in one water line(supply))

Tags: water, water-pressure

What will be the water pressure on the water supply ?
Assuming that i connect these two tank using pvc pipe and t-connector at the middle where the water line will be out

Comment: The pressure should stay the same as one tank, but can use more water before the water pump needs to turn on again.

Comment: So the water pressure will not increase though the volume of water doubled? And the pressure come from two sources thanks i am looking for ways to increase my water pressure for my newly installed water heater

Comment: My main water line is 1' , if ever i am going to install a water pressure booster on my main line that usually have 1/2' pipe, can a reducer of 1 by 1/2 on both ends can be connected ? So i dont need to create new main water line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Water pressure is developed by heigh.

Each foot is ~ .43 psi the tank could be 1 inch in diameter 100’ high and have 43 psi or it could be 50’ in diameter at 100’ and it would still have 43 psi.

So adding parallel tanks only increases the available volume

Increasing the height increases the pressure.

This is why city water is usually in tall tanks the water is pumped up and the pressure is there no pressure tank needed.